# Relative Layouts don’t work on cocos2d-x 3.1?

Tags: c++, cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-3.0

Here there is an example with Relative layout that positions 9 buttons: http://www.cocos2d-x.org/wiki/Containers

I have done something very similar to the wiki example with cocos2d-x 3.1 and tested it on Android and Windows. I have sub-classed `Layer` and added the code below in the `init()` method:

```
Layout* layout = Layout::create();
layout->setLayoutType(LayoutType::RELATIVE);
layout->setContentSize(visibleSize);
layout->setBackGroundColorType(Layout::BackGroundColorType::SOLID);
layout->setBackGroundColor(Color3B::GREEN);
// Size backgroundSize = background->getContentSize();
layout->setPosition(Vec2(visibleOrigin.x + visibleSize.width / 2, visibleOrigin.y + visibleSize.height / 2));
/*_uiLayer->*/addChild(layout);

// top left
Button* button_TopLeft = Button::create("images/ingame/bubbe.png");
layout->addChild(button_TopLeft);

RelativeLayoutParameter* rp_TopLeft = RelativeLayoutParameter::create();
rp_TopLeft->setAlign(RelativeLayoutParameter::RelativeAlign::PARENT_TOP_LEFT);
button_TopLeft->setLayoutParameter(rp_TopLeft);


// top center horizontal
Button* button_TopCenter = Button::create("images/ingame/bubbe.png");
layout->addChild(button_TopCenter);

RelativeLayoutParameter* rp_TopCenter = RelativeLayoutParameter::create();
rp_TopCenter->setAlign(RelativeLayoutParameter::RelativeAlign::PARENT_TOP_CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
button_TopCenter->setLayoutParameter(rp_TopCenter);


// top right
Button* button_TopRight = Button::create("images/ingame/bubbe.png");
layout->addChild(button_TopRight);

RelativeLayoutParameter* rp_TopRight = RelativeLayoutParameter::create();
rp_TopRight->setAlign(RelativeLayoutParameter::RelativeAlign::PARENT_TOP_RIGHT);
button_TopRight->setLayoutParameter(rp_TopRight);


// left center
Button* button_LeftCenter = Button::create("images/ingame/bubbe.png");
layout->addChild(button_LeftCenter);

RelativeLayoutParameter* rp_LeftCenter = RelativeLayoutParameter::create();
rp_LeftCenter->setAlign(RelativeLayoutParameter::RelativeAlign::PARENT_LEFT_CENTER_VERTICAL);
button_LeftCenter->setLayoutParameter(rp_LeftCenter);


// center
Button* buttonCenter = Button::create("images/ingame/bubbe.png");
layout->addChild(buttonCenter);

RelativeLayoutParameter* rpCenter = RelativeLayoutParameter::create();
rpCenter->setAlign(RelativeLayoutParameter::RelativeAlign::CENTER_IN_PARENT);
buttonCenter->setLayoutParameter(rpCenter);


// right center
Button* button_RightCenter = Button::create("images/ingame/bubbe.png");
layout->addChild(button_RightCenter);

RelativeLayoutParameter* rp_RightCenter = RelativeLayoutParameter::create();
rp_RightCenter->setAlign(RelativeLayoutParameter::RelativeAlign::PARENT_RIGHT_CENTER_VERTICAL);
button_RightCenter->setLayoutParameter(rp_RightCenter);


// left bottom
Button* button_LeftBottom = Button::create("images/ingame/bubbe.png");
layout->addChild(button_LeftBottom);

RelativeLayoutParameter* rp_LeftBottom = RelativeLayoutParameter::create();
rp_LeftBottom->setAlign(RelativeLayoutParameter::RelativeAlign::PARENT_LEFT_BOTTOM);
button_LeftBottom->setLayoutParameter(rp_LeftBottom);


// bottom center
Button* button_BottomCenter = Button::create("images/ingame/bubbe.png");
layout->addChild(button_BottomCenter);

RelativeLayoutParameter* rp_BottomCenter = RelativeLayoutParameter::create();
rp_BottomCenter->setAlign(RelativeLayoutParameter::RelativeAlign::PARENT_BOTTOM_CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
button_BottomCenter->setLayoutParameter(rp_BottomCenter);


// right bottom
Button* button_RightBottom = Button::create("images/ingame/bubbe.png");
layout->addChild(button_RightBottom);

RelativeLayoutParameter* rp_RightBottom = RelativeLayoutParameter::create();
rp_RightBottom->setAlign(RelativeLayoutParameter::RelativeAlign::PARENT_RIGHT_BOTTOM);
button_RightBottom->setLayoutParameter(rp_RightBottom);
```

Attached is the result of this code. You can see 9 red bubble buttons. This buttons are in the center of my screen but I have expected to see them in top-right, top-center, ..... and all 9 other places on my screen. Why are they so close to each other?

[image]

Also I don't see layouts solid green color. What is wrong?

Comment: what is the value of visibleSize? on 3rd line: layout->setContentSize(visibleSize);

Comment: `Size visibleSize = Director::getInstance()->getVisibleSize(); Point visibleOrigin = Director::getInstance()->getVisibleOrigin();` Otherwise, this 9 buttons will not be in the center of my screen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Need to change `layout->setContentSize(visibleSize);` to `layout->setSize(visibleSize);`.

Also to debug layout with colors do the following:

```
layout->setBackGroundColor(Color3B::GREEN);
layout->setBackGroundColorType(Layout::BackGroundColorType::SOLID);
```

Comment: `setSize` just calls `setContentSize` now